# load txt data to database in django

Tags: database, django, web-applications

I created a database model in django. But I would like to load initial data (in the form of a txt file, each row coresponding to a data) to this model.  How can I achieve this?

I know how to load data to the mysql directly but not through django.

Answer (score 0):

Django's documentation provides information for your use case, see [Providing initial data for models][1]
You will have to store your data as JSON/YAML/JSON.

You can dump existing data with `python manage.py dumpdata`

Comment: If I directly load data to mysql, would this be a problem?